# list_entry() in list.h returning a warning

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, gnu

Consider this piece of code:

```
 struct Trade
        {
         float Price;
             char* time;
             int shares;
             struct list_head *tradeList;
        };
typedef struct Trade Trade;

    void DisplayTrades(Trade* TBook)
        {
            if(TBook==NULL)
            {
                printf("NO TRADES\n");
                return;
            }
            struct list_head *pos;
            Trade *tmp;
            pos = TBook->tradeList;
            __list_for_each(pos,TBook->tradeList)
            {
                tmp = list_entry((pos),Trade,tradeList);
                printf("Price %f, Time %s, Shares %d\n",tmp->Price,tmp->time,tmp->shares);
            }

        }
```

In this code, when I compile, the compiler gcc returns a warning that `initialization from incompatible pointer type` in the line where list_entry is evoked.
I have used list_entry in other places of the same code, and its working without any glitch. So the only thing that struck me was perhaps I passed unintended variable types to the function, hence attached the definition of structure Trade.The problem persists even then.

Would appreciate,to know where things are going wrong.

**EDIT** : This is just a small snippet from an otherwise large code. I apologise for making it look like, that I am trying to use Trade* object when none exists. In the code, I have indeed used typedef to define struct Trade;

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's going on here when you don't include the definition of list_entry? Presumably it's a macro, since you're passing a type (Trade) to it. P.S. I would guess that it's supposed to be Trade*, not Trade, but I'm shooting in the dark without the definition.

Comment: list_entry() function is defined in list.h of LINUX KERNEL.List.h is a standard header file for Kernel Linked List. I can attach the code, if you insist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, pos must be an actual list head pointer, but the structure field shoud be a list_head and not a list_head pointer :

```
struct Trade
        {
             float Price;
             char* time;
             int shares;
             struct list_head tradeList;
        };
```

And then :

```
  void DisplayTrades(Trade* TBook)
        {
            if(TBook==NULL)
            {
                printf("NO TRADES\n");
                return;
            }
            struct list_head *pos;
            Trade *tmp;
            __list_for_each(pos,&TBook->tradeList)
            {
                tmp = list_entry((pos),Trade,tradeList);
                printf("Price %f, Time %s, Shares %d\n",tmp->Price,tmp->time,tmp->shares);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hmm precisely the thing I was afraid of. Thanks, yes I had the same hunch as well.

Answer (score 0):

In **DisplayTrades** function while declaring the pointer of Trade structure as its argument you must use

**struct Trade * Tbook.**

Comment: @Algorithmist @Lundin Please take a look at my edit. I forgot to add it to the snippet, but the larger code base from where it is taken does contain a typedef of `struct Trade Trade;` (which is now added to the snippet)

Comment: Or better yet, always use 'struct trade'. That avoids the namespace pollution that typedefs incur.

Comment: @Lundin Structure typedefs are frowned upon in Linux kernel code.  This would be bad advice for anyone intending to share code upstream.

Comment: @user611775 There is no such thing as "namespace pollution". Professional programmers have variable/function/type naming in their coding standards, and use naming prefixes.

Comment: @Eric Any particular reason why, beyond religious believes?

Comment: @Lundin There's no technical difference between code that uses typedefs and code that doesn't, but that's not to say that it's entirely stylistic.  One useful result is that it's clear to all users of a struct that they're dealing with a struct, and not something that can be easily passed as a function argument like an integer.  Likewise, when stack space is limited you wouldn't want to accidentally declare a huge struct as a local stack variable.

Comment: @Eric That's pretty much the same argument as "all objects in C++ should be named with the prefix class_ before the variable name, so that you don't risk using a variable without knowing what it does". I.e the old hungarian notation debate, and there's no point in beating that particular dead horse further.

Comment: @Lundin Feel free to take your arguments to the Linux kernel maintainers.  I'm sure they will be happy to reverse their position.  Until then, it remains poor advice to recommend to someone writing kernel code that they disregard the kernel coding style (see Documentation/CodingStyle).

Comment: @Eric So you have no arguments besides "someone else does so". I think you should refrain from commenting on things you have no knowledge of by yourself.

Comment: @Lundin: That might be a compelling argument all by itself.  The first rule of coding style is *use the same style everyone else is using in your shop.*

Comment: @Robert Except the struct notation isn't common. The Win API uses typedef struct, and it is far more used than Linux. So by your argument, the "Linux kernel" style is then wrong. If we skip such religious believes and circle arguments, the typedef style makes struct types consistent, as they look like primitive data types, enums and C++ classes, ie one word and not two.

Comment: @Lundin: If you start work at a company where your coworkers are using [a particular coding style] for all of their code, and they've been using it for years, the proper thing to do is use [their particular coding style] for the code you write for them.  It doesn't matter how common or uncommon you think the style is.